# Отобразить количество новых записей для каждого пользователя

Tags: php, mysql, хранение-данных

Объясните логику. Как вывести количество новых записей (статей) для каждого пользователя?

Например всего записей в базе данных 100.
Первый пользователь заходил последний раз когда в базе было только 80 новостей, получается для него новых записей 20.
А второй пользователь заходил последний раз когда в базе было 90 новостей, для него новых 10.

Как хранить эту информацию?

Сайт на php + mysql.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM news WHERE newsTime >= lastUserLoginTime - как-то так, я думаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно хранить время последнего визита. Запросы будут включать в себя условие "время события больше чем время последнего визита".
Реальные движки усложняют это простое правило списком исключений: пользователю дают возможность отметить что-то "прочитанным".